# Passing struct with anonymous field in Go

Tags: struct, go

Go newbie here. I have two structs, Parent and Child. Child contains Parent as an anonymous field. I want to know how I can pass that struct to a function which is expecting a Parent (and knows nothing about Child). Here's code illustrating what I want to do:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Parent struct {
    Dad string
}

type Child struct {
    Parent
    Son string
}

func myfunc(data Parent) {
    fmt.Printf("Dad is %s\n", data.Dad)
}

func main() {
    var data Child
    data.Dad = "pappy"
    data.Son = "sonny"
    myfunc(data)
}
```

What's the magic declaration of myfunc() to get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code [works on the Go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/FvqwWriGoe) if you just change the second-to-last line to:

```
myfunc(data.Parent)
```

You shouldn't expect to be able to make it work just be changing `myfunc` since you said that `myfunc` cannot know anything about the `Child` class.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I could not find anything talking about this in the docs or elsewhere.

Comment: The type of object you pass as an argument to a function simply has match the type of object it is expecting.  If it expects Parent and you pass Child, most strictly-typed languages have no way to handle that and you shouldn't expect it to work.  So then the question becomes "how do I get the parent out of the child" and it just took me one guess to figure that out.