# Passing struct array with anonymous field in Go

Tags: go

this question is related to [Passing struct with anonymous field in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639794/passing-struct-with-anonymous-field-in-go) but different in that I am dealing with a function that handles an array of Parent items rather than just one struct, ie:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Parent struct {
    Dad string
}

type Child struct {
    Parent
    Son string
}

func myfunc(data []Parent) {
    for n, _ := range data {
        fmt.Printf("Dad is %s\n", data[n].Dad)
    }
}

func main() {
    data := make([]Child, 2)
    data[0].Dad = "pappy"
    data[0].Son = "sonny"
    data[1].Dad = "daddy"
    data[1].Son = "billy"
    myfunc(data)
}
```

I tried to cast data to an array of Parents like `myfunc([]Parent(data))` but that didnt work and obviously the solution of `myfunc(data.Parent)` wont work on an array.

Is there a reasonable solution to this in golang without resorting to creating a new slice or generics which are not out of beta yet?

Cheers

Comment: FYI [go 1.18](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.18), which will include generics support, will be released next month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this even with generics. `data[n].Dad` will not work.

The reasonable way to deal with it is to use an interface, but still, you have to create an interface slice for it:

```
type WithDad interface {
   GetDad() string
}

func (p Parent) GetDad() string {return p.Dad}

func myFunc(data []WithDad) {
   ...
}

...
arr:=make([]WithDad,0,len(data))
for _,x:=range data {
  arr=append(arr,x)
}
myFunc(arr)
```

The reason for this is how the type system works and how slices are passed around. The slice `[]Child` points to an array where each entry is a `Child`. A function that takes `[]Parent` expects a slice whose elements are `Parent`, which is a different type, so you cannot pass one for the other.

The slice `[]WithDad` points to an array where each entry is an interface. Each such entry points to the `Child` or `Parent` entry in another slice.

Comment: thanks for the quick response ... mostly makes sense except for the last 5 lines ... I think you meant to `append(arr, x)` not the `data` ? .. its a shame you need so much cruft to make it work .. I would have thought generics would allow you to write `myFunc` in a way that would accept either a Parent or Child slice since it would infer the type based on the arg so it would know how to traverse the arrays memory to the next element, which seems to be the issue here I think ?

Comment: Correct, `append(arr,x)`, I fixed the answer.

Comment: Generics do not allow accessing a generic type's members, only methods. Thus, you can do the same using interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness I made a complete version of Burak Serdar code I got working (I like it when full working examples are posted for me to cut and paste later :P) ... note I deliberately return a pointer to the `Parent` because in practice its likely you will want to work on that complete struct and not just read 1 field.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type WithDad interface {
    GetDad() *Parent
}

type Parent struct {
    Dad string
}

func (p *Parent) GetDad() *Parent {
    return p
}

type Child struct {
    Parent
    Son string
}

func (c *Child) GetDad() *Parent {
    return &c.Parent
}

func myfunc(data []WithDad) {
    for n, _ := range data {
        fmt.Printf("Dad is %s\n", data[n].GetDad().Dad)
    }
}

func main() {
    data := make([]WithDad, 2)
    data[0] = &Child{Parent: Parent{Dad: "pappy"}, Son: "sonny"}
    data[1] = &Child{Parent: Parent{Dad: "daddy"}, Son: "billy"}
    myfunc(data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your structure with Child being a composite of Parent and a string (which I guess contains the name) makes little sense. A child is not a parent plus their name. In fact you only have one concept, namely Person, who potentially has a parent. Please consider the following approach:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Person struct {
   Name string
   Parent *Person
}

func myfunc(data []Person) {
    for n, _ := range data {
        fmt.PrintLn("My name is", n.Name)
        if n.Parent != nil {
            fmt.PrintLn("My dad is", n.Parent.Name)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    data := make([]Person, 2)
    data[0].Name = "daddy"
    data[1].Name = "billy"
    data[1].Parent = &data[0]
    myfunc(data)
}
```

Comment: sorry this is not my code, I am simply copying it from a similar question I mentioned in the description here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639794/passing-struct-with-anonymous-field-in-go